# Powershell Recursively writing to the same directory

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to grab certain logs from a folder and copy them to my device. The code works, but the output is not what I expect (the other three log files are in the Logs folder). I would just like to have my three files appear. The output I get it below. The console complains about the directory already existing, but that is because it is created prior to my loop I think?

```
$filename = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$files = @('CAS.log', 'LocationServices.log', 'AppDiscovery.log', 'CCMExec.log')

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Copy-Item "c:\Windows\CCM\Logs" -Filter $file -Destination 
    "\\REMOTECOMPUTERNAME\c$\RemoteLogStore\$filename" -Recurse
}
```

[image: What shows up in RemoteLogStore]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$filename` in `"\\REMOTECOMPUTERNAME\c$\RemoteLogStore\$filename"` is the same for every pass of foreach.

Update `$filename` in the loop to what you actually want as a name, or just use the values from `$files`